# Select records with same foreign key but different column value in another table (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

Assume I have two tables with structures as defined.

```
Table1:
| question_id | question_type |
| ----------- | ------------- |
|     1       |       1       |
|     1       |       2       |
Table2:
| question_id | question_type | completed |
| ----------- | ------------- | --------- |
|     1       |       1       |     1     |
```

Now I want to select the record which has no entry in table2, I have done this but it does not work if the question_id is same.

```
Select * from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on
(t1.question_id = t2.question_id and t1.question_type = 1) or
(t1.question_id = t2.question_id and t1.question_type = 2)
where t2.completed is null
and question_id = 1
```

The Problem is whenever there is a record for the same question_id with different type, no record is selected where as the result should give question_id = 1 with question_type = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t2.question_id = t1.question_id AND
          t2.question_type = t1.question_type
);
```

If you wanted to use a join approach, we can try using a left anti-join here:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.question_id = t1.question_id AND
       t2.question_type = t1.question_type
WHERE t2.question_id IS NULL;
```